# Modify Hint which appears at design time in Delphi

Tags: delphi, components, design-time, hint

Usually when a user has the mouse over a component at design time appears a Hint showing the name of the component, the origin, the size and so on.

I would like to customize this hint for my component, for when the mouse is over it at design time it appears something else.

But I didn't find anywhere how to do this.
Can anybody help me with that?

thanks,

Comment: You could probably handle `TApplication.OnHint` from within designtime package of your component and its editors.

Comment: I still don't get it...
the closer that I can get is to change the color of the font using:

Screen.hintfont.color:=clblue;

I also tried to write a new classÇ
TMyHintWindow = class(THintWindow)
and then to substitute the Standart HintWindow with my designed oneÇ
HintWindowClass := TMyHintWindow;

but I don't get anything...

Comment: A component editor (TComponentEditor descand) should be the place for such customizing. But AFAIK is there no function to implement your own hint.

Comment: There is functionality when you have already implemented your own components and it is worth to have a quick overview of some properties of them in a Hint window at Design time...